# How to know the equation of the plot graphs?

Tags: python, differential-equations

I plotted the 1st-order non-linear differential equations.
But I don't know how to know the equations of the plots.
Please forgive my ignorance.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.integrate import odeint
import math

def dy_dx(y,x,z):
    c_1 = 5.0 / (1.38 * 1223.0 * pow(10.0, 28.0)*pow(z,3.0))
    c_2 = pow(10.0, 5.0)
    return c_1 * ( y/math.sqrt(1.0+pow(y, 2.0)) ) * ( ((1.0-pow(y, 3.0))/(z* pow(y,(1.0/3.0)))) - (y * c_2) )

xs = np.linspace(0, pow(10.0, 12.0), pow(10.0, 6.0))
y_0 = 1.0
z = 0.00001
y1 = odeint(dy_dx, y_0, xs, args=(z,))
z = 0.000015
y2 = odeint(dy_dx, y_0, xs, args=(z,))
y1 = np.array(y1).flatten()
y2 = np.array(y2).flatten()

plt.rcParams.update({'font.size': 10})
plt.ylim(0,1.0)
plt.xlabel("x")
plt.ylabel("y")
plt.plot(xs, y1, 'r-')
plt.plot(xs, y2, 'b-')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show()
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: This is numerical integration. If you want an analytic solution, check WolframAlpha

Comment: Actually, I already checked the equation from WolframAlpha. But Fail...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is very improbable that any symbolic solution exists, with third powers and third roots on the right side. The relevant factors for the qualitative behavior are

```
y^(2/3)*(1-y^3-c2*z*y^(4/3))
```

what remains are positive non-zero factors. The one-dimensional dynamic is very simple, roots of the right side are equilibrium positions, the sign in-between tells you if the solutions in that interval are falling or growing.

- At `y=0` you can have branching of solutions similar to `y'=C*y^(2/3)`, as the function is not locally Lipschitz there.
- The polynomial `u^9+a*u^4-1=0`, `a=c_2*z` has exactly one positive root `u_ast`, `y_equi=u_ast^3`, for small `a` it is close to `u=1` (next approximation `u=1/(1+a)^(1/4)~1/(1+a/4)`), for large `a` close to `u=a^(-1/4)`, `y=a^(-3/4)`; and zero or two negative roots. As the right side of the ODE changes sign from positive to negative when passing over `y_equi`, this is a stable equilibrium.

  In your examples with  `c2=1e5` and `z=1e-5` or `z=1.5e-5` one gets `a=1` or `a=1.5` which is in-between, the intermediate value theorem tells us that there is a root between 0 and 1, `u_ast=0.89345331` and `y_equi=0.71320698` in the first case and `u_ast=0.84759991` and `y_equi=0.60893748` in the second. This is exactly what you see in the plot.

That is about all of the theoretical content that you can hope to extract from this equation for positive `y`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer. I think i need to study more about differential equation. Thank you for your help